# How can I hide data for User Roles in Perfex CRM?

Tags: javascript, php, codeigniter

I need a function that hides some parts of Perfex CRM for User Roles. Example: Discount area.

I tried with this code:

```
function hide_fields_nonusers()
{
    if ($role != '4') {    
        <style type="text/css">
            #sconto {
                display: none !important;
            }
            #discount_area {display: none !important;}
        </style>
 }
```

But nothing works, it hides that part for everyone, admin included.

**EDIT**

This one is working, but just for get employee role by ID.

```
/**
     * Get employee role by id
     * @param  mixed $id Optional role id
     * @return mixed     array if not id passed else object
     */
    public function get($id = '')
    {
        if (is_numeric($id)) {

            $role = $this->app_object_cache->get('role-' . $id);

            if ($role) {
                return $role;
            }

            $this->db->where('roleid', $id);

            $role              = $this->db->get(db_prefix() . 'roles')->row();
            $role->permissions = !empty($role->permissions) ? unserialize($role->permissions) : [];

            $this->app_object_cache->add('role-' . $id, $role);

            return $role;
        }

        return $this->db->get(db_prefix() . 'roles')->result_array();
    }
```

Comment: I'm not sure if this is your client or server-side code and it will not compile with either php or javascript, so you're probably just getting that dumped into the browser which then tries to interpret it. Do you have errors in your JavaScript console?

Comment: Nope :/ no errors. It call the STYLE but for everyone, not just for the roles.

Comment: Where do you call that function?

Answer (score 0):

It's likely `hide_fields_nonusers()` would produce a PHP error as this function is  not quite valid PHP code.

To answer your question - based on what you have provided - if you echo out the style tags as PHP code when `$role` does not equal 4 this should work.

***Note:**  If you're not receiving any error messages then it would suggest the function is not executing at all. As Marcel commented, if you can post where you call this function we could look a little closer.*

**PHP**

```
public function hide_fields_nonusers()
{
  
    if ($role != '4') {    
        echo '<style type="text/css">
              #sconto { display:none !important; }
              #discount_area { display:none !important; }
              </style>';
    }
}
```

**OR for JavaScript**

```
if ($role != 4) {
    var css   = '#sconto { display:none !important; }
                 #discount_area { display:none !important; }',
        head  = document.head || document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0],
        style = document.createElement('style');

    head.appendChild(style);

    style.type = 'text/css';
    if (style.styleSheet) {
       // This is required for IE8 and below.
       style.styleSheet.cssText = css;
    } else {
       style.appendChild(document.createTextNode(css));
    }
}
```

Comment: I added it into Custom JavaScript for Admin area only (backend) , a module for Perfex CRM.

Tryed your, but don't work :/ It hide the #sconto for everyone, Role 4 included.

Comment: I've added a javascript solution for you too - updated in the answer- let me know if it's still not working?

Comment: nothing. Both of them not working... With the PHP function the system HIDE for Everyone. I edit the question with a working code but not for the thing I need...